# How to install ASP.NET MVC4 RC on a server (2008 and above )

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Title just about sums it up. I'd like to be able to deploy my application to one of our servers, is there anything spacial that needs to take place, the reason I ask is that a fresh deploy with the deployment tool says I have conflicting dlls, which I was sure to have referenced correctly from the upgrade guide.

Thank you,
Stephen

Comment: I did something like this a few days ago, and all I had to do was use the Web Platform Installer to install MVC.

Comment: @AndreiNeagu The install was on the server? Did you have to install visual studio express?

Comment: No visual studio installed. I just saw it's MVC 4, I installed MVC 3, but there shouldn't be any difference. (just looked and found http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=28942 which looks to need no VS)

Comment: Did you click the "Install ASP.NET MVC 4 RC" button on http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's simple:

1. go to http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc4
2. click the green "Install ASP.NET MVC 4 RC" button to download and run the installer.

Alternatively, you could just install it on your dev machine, then in VS right click on your project and choose "Add Deployable Dependencies..." to automatically include the necessary assemblies in your project for deployment (this will bin deploy MVC).

Another option is to just manually copy the MVC assemblies to the server GAC (copy all the assemblies that are added when using "Add Deployable Dependencies..."), which is what the installer does.

Comment: Have you actually run the installer, it just bootstraps the web platform installer, which chooses to install the ASP.NET MVC 4 (Visual Studio)? I will give you credit for the "Add Deployable Dependencies..."

Comment: Visual Studio isn't required for MVC4, so its not installing that.

Comment: It installs Visual Studio Express if it doesn't find Visual Studio. Have you actually installed this on a server?

Comment: @SPATEN I found this today:  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29935 Maybe it will work for you?

Comment: The first link now has the correct after they RTM'd MVC 4. The installer that will download the needed files only for both dev installs and servers. Remember to uninstall any previous version of MVC 4 that you may have installed.

Comment: The last comment by AngerBall is not correct, at least for me. Used WebPi on Server 2008 R2 and it installed Visual Web Developer 2010 + SP1.

Comment: Really not sure how this was ever the correct answer. At least the part recommending to install Visual Studio on the SERVER. The "Add Deployable Dependencies" is the only working solution I know of. There is no installer to just install the MVC4 runtimes on a server afaik.

Comment: @Nicholi re-read my answer.  I never suggested installing VS on the server, rather installing MVC4 on the development machine (i.e. your local pc) then using the "add deployable dependencies.

Comment: My mistake, need to fully read :)
Hopefully MS will make an installer for MVC4 because they have it for 1-3.

Comment: There's another installer for MVC4 (4.0.20714.0) at  http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/details.aspx?id=30683.  Despite the fact that it says "for Visual Studio 2010 SP1", it didn't seem to try to install anything extra or require VS on the server.

Comment: @mikebridge that one says "Visual Studio 2010 SP1" under "System requirements"

Comment: @roviuser Yes, but I didn't need to install VS.  I think the description is incorrect....

Answer (score 2):

This page hosts the standalone installer for MVC 4:
http://www.microsoft.com/en-ca/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30683

Despite what the page says, Visual Studio is not required to install on a sever.

Answer (score 1):

The "Add Deployable Dependencies..." does no longer exist since VS now always includes the dependend binaries...

[Source](http://samirvaidya.blogspot.dk/2013/02/deployable-dependencies-option-missing.html)