# MVC 4 SimpleMembership HasLocalAccount method not found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, simplemembership

When attempting to access `/account/manage` on the production server I get this error:

```
System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Boolean WebMatrix.WebData.ExtendedMembershipProvider.HasLocalAccount(Int32)'.
   at Microsoft.Web.WebPages.OAuth.OAuthWebSecurity.HasLocalAccount(Int32 userId)
   at PROJECT.Controllers.AccountController.Manage(Nullable`1 message)
   at lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] )
   at System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at Castle.Proxies.AsyncControllerActionInvokerProxy.InvokeActionMethod_callback(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at Castle.Proxies.Invocations.ControllerActionInvoker_InvokeActionMethod.InvokeMethodOnTarget()
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Glimpse.Mvc3.Interceptor.InvokeActionMethodInterceptor.Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
   at Castle.DynamicProxy.AbstractInvocation.Proceed()
   at Castle.Proxies.AsyncControllerActionInvokerProxy.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass6.<>c__DisplayClassb.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar)
   at System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End()
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClasse.<EndProcessRequest>b__d()
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.<GetCallInAppTrustThunk>b__0(Action f)
   at System.Web.Mvc.SecurityUtil.ProcessInApplicationTrust(Action action)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
```

It works fine from the localhost. A google search revealed nothing.

It also should be noted that I'm trying to get this blasted "simple" membership provider to work on a sql server instead of letting it create a database.

p.s. I'm on shared hosting.

**Edit** Added the full stack

Comment: Same problem here.  I'm not on shared hosting - inhouse Win2008 server.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing this function is doing is querying `webpages_Membership` table. My work around is to duplicate the function. If I get a real answer I'll update

```
internal static bool HasLocalAccount(int userId)
        {
            using (YOUREntities db = new YOUREntities ()) 
            {
                webpages_Membership wm = db.webpages_Membership.Where(x => x.UserId == userId).FirstOrDefault();

                if (wm != null) return true;
                return false;
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me too. Cannot understand what the problem is.

Comment: Where did you put this function? Inside the MembershipProvider? Inside your Controller?

Comment: Nevermind.  I'm an idiot.  I should've taken 2 seconds to see its in the Provider before I posted my comment.  Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

The original function posted by Eonasdan was not working for me. I had to tweek it a little bit to get it to work. If it helps anyone, here it is:

```
@functions{
internal static bool HasLocalAccount(int userId){
    using ( var db = Database.Open("your_database_name") ) {
        dynamic id = db.QueryValue(@"SELECT UserId FROM webpages_Membership WHERE UserId=@0", userId);
        return id != null; // returns true if id is not null
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well. In my case it was because I didn't have the MVC 4 binaries installed on my server.

The following SO question has instructions to install it:

- [How to install ASP.NET MVC4 RC on a server (2008 and above )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10941011/how-to-install-asp-net-mvc4-rc-on-a-server-2008-and-above)

Then retry your account/manage link - it should work.

NB remember to unhack your HasLocalAccount() (if you implemented the workaround contained in other answers here).