# Update Membership property. Method not supported

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-membership

I've tried to research the exception I'm getting for a couple of hours now with no progress.

I'm simply trying update a Membership profile using the following code:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(username);
user.IsApproved = false;
Membership.UpdateUser(user);
```

So the problem is with the last line in the above code sample. The server is throwing an exception stating that the specified method is not supported. I have no build errors and I believe I'm using the correct libraries.

Any idea why something like this would occur?

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Specified method is not supported.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.

Source Error: 


Line 58:                     MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser("asdf", false);
Line 59:                     user.IsApproved = false;
Line 60:                     Membership.UpdateUser(user);
Line 61: 
Line 62:                     // -----------------

    Source File: d:\Coding\ASP.NET\Source\Controllers\AccountController.cs    Line: 60 

    Stack Trace: 


    [NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.]
       WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider.UpdateUser(MembershipUser user) +38206
       System.Web.Security.MembershipUser.Update() +91
       System.Web.Security.Membership.UpdateUser(MembershipUser user) +19
       Source.Controllers.AccountController.Register(RegisterModel model) in d:\Coding\ASP.NET\Source\Controllers\AccountController.cs:60
       lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +180
       System.Web.Mvc.ActionMethodDispatcher.Execute(ControllerBase controller, Object[] parameters) +14
       System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +211
       System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2 parameters) +27
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass42.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__41() +28
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass8`1.<BeginSynchronous>b__7(IAsyncResult _) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass39.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__33() +57
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +223
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4f.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously>b__49() +223
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__36(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +48
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass2a.<BeginInvokeAction>b__20() +24
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass25.<BeginInvokeAction>b__22(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +102
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +57
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +43
       System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__18(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +14
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +57
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
       System.Web.Mvc.Controller.System.Web.Mvc.Async.IAsyncController.EndExecute(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +10
       System.Web.Mvc.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__3(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +25
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass4.<MakeVoidDelegate>b__3(IAsyncResult ar) +23
       System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`1.End() +62
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +47
       System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.System.Web.IHttpAsyncHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult result) +9
       System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute() +9629708
       System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +155

    Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET Version:4.0.30319.1
```

7929

Comment: Can you post the exception and the stack trace?

Comment: Which Membership provider are you using? If it's the Default then you're probably using the SimpleMembership Provider which ships with MVC 4

Comment: I am using the built-in provider, correct.

Comment: Thanks, guys. I'll look into how to update a user profile using the simple membership provider.

Comment: I've had a bunch of problems with `SimpleMembership` [see also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12413780/mvc-4-simplemembership-haslocalaccount-method-not-found) I ended up writing my own function to duplicate it :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

SimpleMembership, as the name implies, is very simple and does not implement all of the MembershipProvider methods; just those required for MVC basic authentication and authorization. If you try to use a method that is not implemented you will get that exception.  You can either create your own MembershipProvider from scratch or you can inherit from SimpleMembership and implement the methods that are not implemented.

Comment: I have same problem, Did you mean that I should add a field to the UserProfile in My models, 
It is not possible to use Membership?

Comment: @ar.gorgin - No, I am talking about extending SimpleMembershipProvider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.simplemembershipprovider(v=vs.111).aspx or creating your own MembershipProvider http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e(v=vs.140).aspx

Comment: Thanks, Sorry, Can you add a sample for defined `SimpleMembershipProvider`. I use `var membership = (WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider)Membership.Provider;` bu i get error :(